# Why does Xcode think an iPad Air 2 is an iPhone instead of an iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

When attempting to install an adhoc distribution .ipa file to various devices, I am getting the following error when attempting to install to an iPad Air 2.

"**Can't install application**

The application at /Users/username/Downloads/AdHocDistribution.ipa can only be installed on iPads."

Ok, sure, it's marked as "iPad Only" (as opposed to "iPhone Only" or "Both"), but I'm trying to install it *to an iPad.*

What's going on?  Why is an iPad Air 2 not an iPad?

Edit: Worth noting that it does install successfully on iPad 2 and iPad 4 devices.

When I create a build that's marked for iPhone, it *does* install successfully on the iPad Air 2.  So Xcode definitely thinks it's an iPhone.  I just can't figure out why.

After wiping both the iPad Air 2 and the mac, and performing OS reinstalls, the problem no longer reproduces.  The iPad in question was not jailbroken, so that's not the cause.  I remain baffled as to what caused it.  Hopefully my encounter will prove helpful to someone else in the future.